# NetworkService account access to a shared folder (WinSrv 2012R2)

Tags: windows-server-2012, file-sharing, user-accounts

We have services running under IIS with pool setup to run under NetworkService identity. If the service required access to a shared folder on a remote server, on previous versions of WinServer we just added the "ServerA$" account to the list of user permission of the share.

Now, in Windows Server 2012 (R2, probably some previous versions as well) the computer account is no longer selectable in the object type window when searching for the user:

[image: Shared folder - object types when selecting permission]
(There used to be "Computers" checkbox here)

Now, how do we allow access to a shared folder on ServerB to a process running under NetworkService Identity on ServerA?

Comment: Are you trying to give "normal" SMB Share rights on your share? I looked on my Windows Server 2012R2 Server and checked the Filerightes of and folder. On my system i can select Computers and serviceaccounts...

Comment: (sorry for this step-by-step, I want to make sure we're on the same page) - Right click folder, choose "Share with" -> "Specific people", choose "Find people", on the popup click the "Object types" - there's no computers account here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use advanced sharing for this, go to
Properties
Sharing Tab
Advanced Sharing
Tick 'Share this Folder'
Click Permissions
Click Add
Click Object Types

The computer object will be shown in the list of available objects

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you have to go to properties --> sharing --> advanced shareing. There you can choose the computer under the "object types".

But i would prevere to set the share to "everyone" and then change the rights over the NTFS-User rights. So you only have to manage the rights on one side...